# Constructor's Private scope

Tags: java

Given this code snippet, could you explain why it woks?

The thing is that the class constructor is marked private, so should not it prevent us to call it with new operator?

```
public class Alpha {
 protected Alpha() {}
}
class SubAlpha extends Alpha {
 private SubAlpha() {System.out.println("ok");}
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  new SubAlpha();
 }
}
```

It all works because the static method is part of the class and it can see all private fields and methods, right? Outside this "new" initialization would never work?

Answer (score 5):

The only **`private`** constructor in your question is `SubAlpha`, which `SubAlpha` itself is calling. There's no issue, a class can call its own private methods. The `Alpha` constructor is `protected`, so `SubAlpha` has access to it.

**Edit**: Re your edit: Yes, exactly. A *separate* class (whether a subclass or not) would not have access to `SubAlpha`'s private constructor and could not successfully construct a `new SubAlpha()`.

Example 1:

```
public class Beta
{
    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SubAlpha();
//      ^--- Fails with a "SubAlpha() has private access in SubAlpha"
//           compilation error
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class SubSubAlpha extends SubAlpha
{
    private subsubAlpha()
    {
//  ^== Fails with a "SubAlpha() has private access in SubAlpha"
//      compilation error because of the implicit call to super()
    }
}
```

This is, of course, constructor-specific, since scope is always member-specific. If a class has a *different* constructor with a different signature and a less restrictive scope, then a class using it (including a subclass) can use that other constructor signature. (In the case of a subclass, that would require an explicit call to `super(args);`.)

Answer (score 1):

The code works as the main method is also in the same class. You may not be able to initialize SubAplha from a different class.